# Issue in mysql table creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a table called benificiaries where I have three columns

```
customerid
accountno
bank
```

The condition should be one `customerid` can have only one unique `accountno`. But another `customerid` can have the same `accountno` and same unique (only once). So I cant give primary key to `accountno`. Even for `customerid` I can't give primary key, since one `customerid` can have multiple records with unique `accountno`.

How can we create table in this case? Any ideas?

Comment: Add new column of name id which is primary key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple-column unique index.

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (
    id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customerid         INT NOT NULL,
    accountno  INT NOT NULL,
    bank INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX name (customerid,accountno)
);
```

Documentation here.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: at least quote _some_ code the OP can use from that link

Comment: I dont want to enter id every time.can we pust auto increment for id?

Comment: Sure, I added AUTO_INCREMENT to id field. Check CREATE TABLE syntax please.

Comment: one last query..If I want to insert records like this

  (1,123,12345,hsbc) (2,123,54321,hdfc) (3,111,12345,hsbc)..will your query allows?

Comment: yes, though you can specify what fields you want to isnert and don't need to ever care about the `id`

Comment: @tanaydin Table is not getting created.Giving the below error

Comment: @LucaKiebel  { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name(customerid,accountnumber)' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }

Comment: @tanaydin My bad ignore..It got created

Comment: @tanaydin Hey ..But it is allowing me to insert the same accountno twice for particular customerid..which shouldnt be

Comment: Inserted data
data [ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    customerid: 'harish3405',
    name: 'suvajit',
    accountnumber: '3604123',
    bank: 'icici' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 11,
    customerid: 'harish3405',
    name: 'suvajit',
    accountnumber: '3604123',
    bank: 'icici' } ]

Comment: @LucaKiebel Still This query is accepting multiple records like this (1,123,12345,hsbc)(11,123,12345,hsbc)

Comment: @LucaKiebel Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If one customerid can have only 1 unique account number then how can you expect duplicates in terms of customer id in that table?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply set a primary key to another column and make the customerid unique. I think this is what you want to have. Now every customerid is unique, but many costomerids can have the same accountno.

```
CREATE TABLE benificiaries(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  customerid INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  accountno  INT NOT NULL,
  bank INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: if  i want to insert 2 records like this
    (1,123,12345,hsbc)
    (2,123,54321,hdfc)
Is this possible.?Uisng your query.not sure?

Comment: Yeah my bad I didn't understand the question in the right way

Answer (score -1):

database can't manage all the business constraints within the data model. For the case, you might address elementary constraints with indexes (multiple column index for customerid, accountno and simple column index for accountno to perform search on the other way), add an auto-increment id and deal the business constraints in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Just set your customer_id as a primary key then regarding the concept that a only two customer_id can have same account number once, will depend on the process of your App or System.

```
CREATE TABLE `tmpr_map`.`tbl_example` 
(`customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`account_number` VARCHAR NOT NULL , `bank_amount` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```